# how to make the model glft center in Aframe?

Tags: aframe, gltf

i am trying to make my model gltf to me center before it click to VR mode, but not showing thought i set the postion inside entity

it something like this

```
       <div class="" style="height: 800px; width: 900px">
            <a-scene embedded>
                <a-assets>
                    <a-asset-item id="tree" src="static/models/Box/Box.gltf"></a-asset-item>
                </a-assets>

                <a-gltf-model src="#tree" camera position="0 1.6 0"></a-gltf-model>
<!-- <a-entity camera gltf-model="#tree" position="0 1.6 0"></a-entity> -->
            </a-scene>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to place the pivot of a gltf model, you need to do that in the 3D modelling program, and export the gltf again. Aframe used the center as the pivot location that comes in with the gltf import.